# How to display a cookie value on a php page that was set on another php page

Tags: php, cookies

on a php page called 'article.php' i set up a cookie and display it and all works correctly

```
# www.mywebpage/library/article.php

setcookie("fanclub_articlesvisited", 'test');

echo $_COOKIE['fanclub_articlesvisited']; //displays perfectly after refreshing
```

on another php page, called 'new.php' i go

```
# www.mywebpage/library/new.php

if (isset($_COOKIE['fanclub_articlesvisited'])) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

but it always echoes 'not found'. I thought cookies is always global?

I even try

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

and it shows

```
Array ( )
```

as if it doesnt even exists?

What's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, are these two scripts running on the same domain?

Comment: yes. they are running on my development server on the same domain. I've edited my question to add that important detail

Comment: Try this is another browser, just to confirm it isn't your browser not accepting the cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are `www.mywebpage/library/article.php` and `www.mywebpage/library/new.php` the actual URLs you're accessing? I noticed that you didn't provide a `path` parameter when setting your cookie, so perhaps the problem is caused by you trying to access the cookie from a directory outside of the one where the cookie was set.

Try this instead:

```
setcookie("fanclub_articlesvisited", 'test', 0, '/');
```

### Explanation:

By default, a cookie will only be sent in pages above the directory from which it was set. So for example, a cookie set at this URL:

```
http://example.com/some_stuff/foo.php
```

will be visible here:

```
http://example.com/some_stuff/bar.php
http://example.com/some_stuff/subdirectory/foo.php
```

but not here:

```
http://example.com/other_stuff/foo.php
http://example.com/index.php
```

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/setcookie) has more information.

Comment: yeap. that did work. Im using SEO friendly url's and it's probably the reason why it was failing... by adding the '/' it worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

test.php

```
  <?Php
  setcookie("fanclub_articlesvisited", 'test123');
  echo $_COOKIE['fanclub_articlesvisited']; //displays perfectly after refreshing
  ?>
```

test2.php

```
  <?php 
  echo htmlentities($_COOKIE['fanclub_articlesvisited'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
  ?>
```

for me this works

Comment: `$_SESSION` is not the same as `$_COOKIE`